# Dúvida em criação de variável jQuery

Tags: jquery, declaração-de-variável

Pesquisando materiais sobre jQuery reparei que alguns artigos usam dois tipos de declaração de variávels, algumas usando o cifrão e outras não, como no exemplo abaixo:

**Alternativa 1**

```js
var $row =$("<tr/>")
```

**Alternativa 2**

```js
var row =$("<tr/>")
```

Existe alguma diferença entre as duas formas? Quando usar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regras gerais para a construção de nomes para as variáveis ​​(identificadores únicos) são:

- Os nomes podem conter letras, números, sublinhados e sinais de dólar.
- Os nomes devem começar com uma letra
- Nomes também pode começar com $ e _
- Os nomes são maiúsculas de minúsculas (y e Y são variáveis ​​diferentes)
- As palavras reservadas (como palavras-chave de JavaScript) não podem ser usados ​​como nomes

Desta situação não ha uma diferença além de se tratar de variáveis diferente.

#### Situação para uso

- Algumas vezes pessoas quando ja trabalham com PHP tem costume de declarar as variáveis com `$` na frente para manter algum padrão, ou psicológico. Eu pessoalmente não gosto.
- Em alguns casos quando se esta trabalhando com encapsulamento ou name-space pode se definir que variáveis globais devem começar com `_` e variáveis internas com `$`, podendo variar para maiúsculo ou minúsculo, mas isso já é padrão de projeto.

#### Concluindo

Ambas são variáveis independentes, em quesito de nomenclatura no javascript não à diferença. Podendo haver caso se esteja trabalhando com algum padrão de projeto, mas meramente organizacional e psicológico.

Answer (score 3):

Bem, não há diferença entre as duas declarações.

tanto **row** quanto **$row** são variáveis normais.

A "diferença" está na legibilidade do código em si. Há uma certa convenção de nomeação de variáveis que irão guardar um objeto JQuery, onde essas são iniciadas por cifrão ($).

**Exemplo:**

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
var $input = $("<input>");
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

As duas formas funcionam iguais, acaba sendo uma questão de convenção por que alguns programadores gostarem de criar váriaveis com o cifrão no começo para identificar que aquela váriavel possui algum código jquery.

Answer (score 1):

o cifrão (**$**) é um acrônimo de jQuery. Muitas pessoas utilizam ele em variáveis apenas para representar de que os elementos trabalhados pertencem ao objeto jquery, e não somente a um atributo da função ou método, isso não é uma regra, mas uma maneira de organizar o código.

Esse acrônimo, muitas vezes é substituído para evitar conflitos entre códigos como **mootools** por exemplo.

```
var jKelly = jQuery.noConflict();
jKelly( "div" ).text('Olá Kelly');
```

Comment: Obrigada a todos, consegui entender melhor!